# Adding title in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to add, let's say, some kind of a title. My PHP returns something like this:

```
[{"Grad":"Beograd","Predmet":"matematika"},{"Grad":"Novi_Sad","Predmet":"matematika"},{"Grad":"Beograd","Predmet":"matematika"}]
```

And I would like to get something like this

```
{"lista"[{"Grad":"Beograd","Predmet":"matematika"},{"Grad":"Novi_Sad","Predmet":"matematika"},{"Grad":"Beograd","Predmet":"matematika"}]}
```

This is my PHP

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db);

if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} 


$sql = "SELECT Grad, Predmet FROM lista";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


$rows = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {


        $rows[] = $row; 

}

mysqli_close($con);

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$rows = (object) array('lista' => $rows);
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: $rows['lista'][] = $row ?

Comment: That wouldn't get encoded as a JSON object, just as a nested array.